# Exchange 2007 Management Shell (EMS) not working

Tags: powershell, exchange-2007

Windows Server Standard FE (2008) - Service Pack 2 (SBS)
Exchange 2007 (08.01.0436.000) - Version 8.1 (Build 2406)

(Tried to find the Service Pack version, but the only way that I can see to do this is to use the Shell, which does not work).

Nothing in the Event Viewer.

Whether using the Start Menu shortcut or loading the snap-in manually from PowerShell, I get the same error message:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\exshell.psc1" -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\Exchange.ps1'"
>
> WARNING: The following errors occurred when loading console C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\bin\exshell.psc1:
>
> Cannot load Windows PowerShell Snap-In Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin because of the following error:
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.AdminPSSnapIn' to type 'System.Management.Automation.CustomPSSnapIn'.
>
> Command '. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\Exchange.ps1'' could not be run because some Windows PowerShell Snap-Ins did not load.

We've tried removing .Net 4.5 and installing .Net 4.0 (read there is a problem with Exchange 2010 and 4.5).

We can't import a new SSL certificate without the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Exact versions of Windows and Exchange 2007 would help here.

Have you tried putting the management tools on to another system, then loading the Shell from there?

Exchange 2007 doesn't use Netframework 4.x at all, it is a 3.5 application.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the .Net version, but I'm grasping at straws here. I added Server and Exchange versions. Not sure about the Exchange version, so I am updating it now to Service Pack 3 (maybe that will fix it).

Comment: If you weren't on SP3, then installing that will often fix a lot of issues because it effectively reinstalls Exchange. Don't forget to install the latest rollup for Exchange 2007 as well.

Comment: FYI, you are on SP1, as that is 08.01 - when you got SP3 it will change to 08.03. I would also check that you have everything else updated for the server - run Microsoft Update - but of course don't install netframework 4.6!

Comment: Yea, I'm doing this for a client and made the assumption that was on the most recent service pack (because I'm a service pack junkie), guess I should have looked at that already (love you Wes, if you are reading this).

Comment: I got Service Pack 3 installed, however, EMS still does not run and I have 8 updates that will not install. 6 security updates and 2 rollups - Update Rollup 8-v2 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 3 (KB2756497) & Update Rollup 17 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 3 (KB3056710).  Both of these rollups fail to install with a message about setup exiting prematurely and I've tried the "fix" (which is supposed to be a UAC workaround, but UAC is disabled on this machine) and the fix does not work either. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Windows Update doesn't always offer the Exchange rollups correctly.
Therefore the first thing to do is download the latest rollup *17 at the time of writing) manually. Then open an elevated Command Prompt and run the update from there. After the service pack installation, is it failing with the same error or something else?

Comment: Already tried that - that is the "fix" I was referring to. Everywhere I've found this issue states that the "premature ending" message is due to UAC, but UAC is disabled on this machine. Still, I've tried installing manually via an elevated command prompt and I still get the same message. The EMS is still failing the same way (same error message).

Comment: UAC being disabled shouldn't be required, and I can actually find that it causes more problems than it resolves. You need to look at the log for the installation (which should be in the Exchange setup logs directory) to see what the actual reason for the failure is. 

As for the original error, can you try a new account with the relevant permissions. I have seen it be the Windows profile that can cause some odd errors, and a new account is the quickest way to test.

Comment: I enabled UAC to try to resolve this issue. No change. I used a brand new account (Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins, Exchange Organization Administrators). No change. I looked at the logs - do you mean there should be a log for the rollup? If so, there's not. I did find setup errors from a Service Pack 3 installation that indicate that the user was not in the 'Schema Admins' and 'Enterprise Admins' groups, but that was under my account and I am a member of both of those groups.

Comment: In C:\ExchangeSetupLogs there should be a log file for the rollup installation. Although this is sounding like there could be more wrong with the server than just this. Was it fully patched with everything else? Service Pack for Windows etc?

Comment: There is no log for the rollup in C:\ExchangeSetupLogs. Yes, it was fully patched for everything else, Windows Server Standard FE (SBS, Server 2008, Service Pack 2).

Comment: Attempted to install the rollup adding these parameters: /lxv* c:\<path>\<filename>.log. Found this error: rollup Installation success or error status: 1603. Found this error: msgINTERIMUPDATEDETECTED. Removed this update: KB2506146. Now the rollups are installing (at least 8v2 is)!

Comment: I just checked and EMS is working - the problem was KB2506146. :) What should I do with this question?